# DatePickerState execute function Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, datepicker, android-jetpack-compose

I have a Datepicker in jetpack compose and I save DatePickerState in a data class.

I need to execute a function in the Viewmodel when the date is changed (only have DatePickerState.inmilis) and I don’t know how to start with it.

I’m trying to get the before selected date and the actual in a compose and when it is different call a function on the viewmodel, but I don’t like this method, because I want to do this on the viewModel to not charge of responsability to the compose..

```
var lastDate: Long? by remember { mutableStateOf(null)}
var newDate: Long? by remember { mutableStateOf(datePickerState.selectedDateMillis)}

if (newDate != datePickerState.selectedDateMillis){
    lastDate = newDate
    newDate = datePickerState.selectedDateMillis
    newDate?.let(onDateChanged)
}
```

Comment: So you want to handle this purely in the view model? Why not just check previous and new date in the view model function that accepts new dates before updating the state?

Comment: Yes I think it's better to hold this on the viewmodel and not in a compose. Mmm.. I think I'm not understanding you. What is the function you talking about?

Comment: Whatever function you are using to tell the view model it has a new date to put in the state.